# Incremental source generators with Collect(): what determines target assembly?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

Say we have an incremental source generator like this:

```cs
    public override void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        var provider = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(FilterSyntaxNode, TransformSyntaxNode)
            .Where(model => model is not null)
            .Collect();

        context.RegisterSourceOutput(provider, GenerateSource!);
    }
```

Due to the call to `Collect()`, `GenerateSource` needs to accept an `ImmutableArray<TModel>` instead of just a single `TModel`.

Now consider the following assembly structure:

- Project **Application** references project **Domain**
- Project **Domain** references the **source generator package**

When working with a generator that does *not* `Collect()`, the generated code belongs to the assembly that its *input* resides in. So source generated based on types from **Domain** ends up in **Domain**, and source generated based on types from **Application** end up in that assembly. Great.

How is the target assembly determined when multiple inputs from different assemblies are combined with `Collect()`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: usually all generated code ends up in the project referencing the generator, they do not modify other assemblies and the namespaces generated types end up in, are determined by your generated code, so your question doesn't make much sense to me. if the reference should inherited, the SG should run for both projects separately.